# Asp.Net C# Dynamic GridView Options and Values on Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, dynamic

I have a GridView Control that displays data from a table on Page_Load as well as a progress bar in one column and a button in another.

It then loops through each row of the Table and depending on the values, hides said button (i.e. if the 1st column value = "Open" then the button in the 8th column is hidden). It uses a simple foreach loop;

```
foreach (GridViewRow Row in MyGridView.Rows)
{
    if(Row.Cells[0].Text == "Open")
    {
        Row.Cells[7].Text = "";            
    }
}
```

This is working absolutely fine on page load... unfortunately once the user sorts the data by the column values it doesn't work. I can get the event to fire (testing between OnSort and OnSorting amongst other events on the board) but it isn't actually making any changes to the table.

It seems the issues lays somewhere in how I'm attempting to initiate it... does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work this out through more testing. For anyone with a similar problem, use the `DataGridViews OnPreRender` Event.